# about sentence " I did start it "?

Tags: do-support

How did Paula Hawkins say "I did start it" in her novel *The Girl on the Train*?

> I haven’t got much done today. I was supposed to sort out my application for the fabrics course at St. Martins; I did start it.

And what is the meaning of "I haven't got much done today" 
how did she use have + got + done ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get something done is to complete a task.

"I haven't managed to finish much work today. I had intended to complete my application [for the course]; I did [at least] start to do it."

Answer (score -1):

"Have got" has the same meaning of "have" or "got" alone, but with a stronger feeling
So you can say this is just for confirmation